# Finite set with $\sup\{S\} \notin S $

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Just a quick question about sets.

Can anyone here think of an example of a finite set $S$ where the $\sup\{S\} \notin S $ ?

I found this on a past exam paper for college, and am unsure if there exists a finite set with this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking of a subset of real numbers then it can't be: if $\;S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}\;$ then we can **actually** order the elements of $\;S\;$ (all the time wrt the usual order), say $\;S=\{s_{i_1},...,s_{i_n}\}\;$ , with $\;s_{i_1}<s_{i_2}<...<s_{i_n}\;$ , and then clearly $\;\sup(S)=s_{i_n}\in S\;$

Comment: Thats the logic I had, but I'm wondering if there could be one in the Natural numbers, rationals or even integers....

Comment: @Paulistic the same argument holds for all finite sets of real numbers (which includes the natural numbers, integers, and rationals).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah, I get that now, the rationals, integers and natural numbers would all be ordered and finite too as they's subsets of the reals. Thanks for Clearing this up guys. Been studying past papers for a while and I'm beginning to question even the most obvious examples.

Comment: This answer is not correct. An order relation needs not to be linear. Thus, the set may not contain any supremum, or if it exists it is not necessarily an element of $S$.

Comment: The answer is correct *in the real numbers*, as written and proven. Of course a relation doesn't "have" to be linear, and there are several answers addressing this, @Keinstein

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the context. Is the following example allowed?

Consider a set $X$, and its power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$, ordered by inclusion. It admits a supremum, where $\sup\{A, B \} = A \cup B$, for $A, B \subseteq X$.

Now if you take $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1, 3\}$ and $S = \{A, B\}$, then $\sup(S) = X \notin S$.

Comment: The basic nature of the question probably points towards the possibility the OP is more or less beginning with this stuff and most probably is dealing with real numbers. Yet this is very nice, so +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks, and then I agree with you on what OP is likely to have had in mind.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasCaranti but yeah, its an Introduction to Analysis course, and we never covered power sets. But its interesting that outside of what I have learnt some things can still happen like this

Answer (score 1):

Every finite linear order admits a maximum, so if $S$ is linearly ordered, $\sup S=\max S\in S$.

Therefore the ambient order cannot be a linearly ordered set, and $S$ itself must witness that. Knowing this we can now have plenty of examples:

1. $S=\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{X\}$ where $X$ is a finite set with at least two elements, and the order is $\subseteq$.
2. Order the natural numbers by divisibility, $k\preceq m\iff k\mid m$, and take $S$ to be any finite set of prime numbers with at least two elements.
3. Consider the order on $\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$ defined by $(m,i)\preceq(n,j)\iff m\leq n\land i\leq j$. Then take the set $\{(n+1,0),(n,1)\}$.

Comment: This is a great answer. +1